# perf report. Twice or more entries that takes too much time

Tags: perf

I present the perf's output of my samples collected with the `perf -g -p`.

I don't know how to interpret the fact that there is a lot entries that takes > 90% time. After all, if a process spent 90% time in `start_thread` (and its children) it is not possible that that process spent > 90% time in `java_start` (for example) as well.

Please explain

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us start with the command that you used to perform a `perf record`.

The use of `-g` switch indicates that you are trying to collect the information about callchains along with the information about overhead.

The overhead can be shown in two columns as **Children** and **Self** when perf collects callchains.

```
  Children      Self  Command          Shared Object                Symbol                                                                                                                                 ◆
-   14.19%     0.00%  qemu-system-x86  [unknown]                    [.] 0xbbbe258d4c544155                                                                                                                 ▒
     0xbbbe258d4c544155                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
     __libc_start_main                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
   + main                                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
```

The 'self' overhead values indicate the count of timer ticks (period values) that is spent in an individual function. So if only the 'self' overhead values were to be displayed in `perf report`, the sum of the overhead values would always be **100%** as you are probably expecting.

However, when both 'children' and 'self' columns get displayed in `perf report`, things become a lot more confusing. The 'children' overhead column sums up the overhead values of all of the child functions that are being called from a parent.

In your case, `start_thread` has a 'children' overhead percentage of 98.78%, but its 'self' overhead is 0.00%. This means that the sum of the time spent by the execution in all of the functions that are being called by `start_thread`(i.e. **child functions**) is 98.78%, but `start_thread` alone does not lead to any overheads at all, since its 'self' overhead is 0.00%.

Now coming to `Java_start`. It looks like `start_thread` calls `Java_start`. Once again, the 'children' overhead for `Java_start` will include the sum of overheads of all the functions that are being called by it. That is why, you again see almost the same overhead values for both functions.

Consider an example--

```
void main(){
  do_main();
}

void do_main() {
  foo();
}

void foo(){
  bar();
}

void bar(){
  /* do something here */
}
```

Let us assume the 'self' overheads of `foo()` and `bar()` are 60% and 40% respectively. And also let `main()` and `do_main()` each have 'self' overheads of 0% and 0% respectively.

Then the 'children' overheads of each of the functions will be like -

```
main()       children: 100%    self: 0%

do_main()    children: 100%    self: 0%

foo()        children: 100%    self: 60%

bar()        children:  40%    self: 40%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for great explanation :). 
It seems that `perf record -p PID` samples on main thread of `PID`. Is it possible to sample all `PID`'s threads?

Comment: Hi @J.Doe, no when you attach `perf record` to an existing process, it samples on all of the threads of the PID. (This is by default the feature of all of the perf commands- like `perf stat` etc.)

Comment: I have some questions about this example. Is a function always its own child function? For example, in your example, both the "children" and "self" values of bar are 40%. Bar is at the end of the callchain and does not call any functions, so why are both the "children" and "self" values of bar 40%? If a function is always its own child function, then I can understand why the "children" value of foo is 100%, as children(foo) = self(bar) + self(foo).